# How to set ImageView to chang color of foreground when click?

Tags: android-imageview

I want to call image from server and I use image in background of imageview when I click on button it will change foreground color of imageview to black (still show image but darker)

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
image.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123,73,122), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

Found this from http://suryaandriodapps.blogspot.com/2011/12/apply-color-to-imageview-png-file.html?zx=e251678f0452e874 and worked for me..